# EOF Error on pickling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, eoferror

Here is the code that is causing this error.

sending thread:

```
 data = pickle.dumps (object);
```

receiving thread:

```
 self.object = pickle.loads(data) // Erroneous line
```

The error displayed is

```
    self.object = pickle.loads(data)
EOFError
```

Also to add to details, this error occurs only 50% of the times. The other 50% of the times, there is no error!

Comment: Are you sure you received all bytes for the pickle on the receiving thread?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters Do you suggest, I should put a sleep call before pickling to give enough time for all bytes to arrive?

Comment: I am suggesting you ensure that all data has arrived before handing it to the `pickle.loads` function.

Comment: I am very new to network programming. Can you please suggest a way of doing it? Probably printing and checking the pickled data could help

Comment: We need to see your code. How are you sending and receiving it? If you're passing them over a TCP (stream) socket, and just receiving with `data = self.sock.recv()`, that won't work, and we can explain what will. If you're using threads within the same process directly sharing some global variable without locking, that's a different problem that we can explain how to fix. And so on. But with just the information you've given us, there are 100 things that could be wrong, and we can't explain how to fix all 100 of them.

Comment: Meanwhile, for debugging help, your idea of printing the data on both the sending and receiving sides to compare them is a great one. (But you may be able to just print the _length_ of the data, which will be a lot easier to read and compare.)

Comment: Hey are u closing the pickle file? or make sure the pickle files are getting closed properly.

Comment: @MevinBabu: He's using `loads` and `dumps` and passing strings around, not using `load` and `dump`, so presumably there are no pickle files to close.

Comment: @MevinBabu: Thanks a lot for this hint! I had the same error and in my case the this was indeed the reason.

Answer (score 6):

Given the comments, I have a guess at the *most likely* problem, but there's at least a 50% chance I've guessed wrong, in which case… tell me and I'll delete the answer.

I'm guessing you're trying to use a stream socket as if it were a sequence of messages. This is a very common problem among network-programming novices.

Imagine the sender does something like this:

```
data = pickle.dumps(object);
self.sock.sendall(data)
```

And the receiver does something like this:

```
data = self.sock.recv(4096)
self.object = pickle.loads(data)
```

This may work 99% of the time in simple tests, but in real-world use it will not work. You will receive partial messages, or multiple messages in a single call, or some fun combination of the above (like half of message 2, all of message 3, and a third of message 4).

So, you'll pass a partial message to `loads` and get back an error telling you that it's not a complete pickle.

That's not because anything is broken; that's how it's *supposed* to work. A (TCP) socket is a *stream*: a sequence of bytes, not a sequence of messages. Any structure you want on top of that, you have to build into the data.

This means you have to design and implement a protocol—some way of knowing when each message is finished. The simplest protocols are probably lines (obviously only useful if a message can never have an unescaped newline) and [netstrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring), but anything that gives you an unambiguous way of looking at some data and saying "This is message 0, this is message 1, etc." will work.

Normally, this means appending received data onto some buffer, and looping over the messages in that buffer. For example, with lines, instead of this:

```
while True:
    line = sock.recv(4096)
    do_stuff(line)
```

… you need this:

```
rdbuf = ''
while True:
    rdbuf += sock.recv(4096)
    lines = rdbuf.split('\n')
    rdbuf = lines[-1]
    for line in lines[:-1]:
        dostuff(line)
```

If you think about it, this is no different from a file. Imagine this code:

```
with open('foo.data', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('123')
    f.write('45')
with open('foo.data', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        number = f.read()
```

This is going to read `'12345'`, not `'123'`. If you want to get the `'123'`, you need some way of knowing to only read 3 bytes. Sticking in a length prefix, or adding whitespace as a separator, or just having external knowledge that the first number is always 3 digits long… *anything* works, but you have to do *something*.